# wire.h extern twowire object error

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, optimization, arduino

i use eclipse to make projects for arduino.I included "Wire.h" to a new class and at the arduinocore library project i get error at the Wire.h header. the error is at the line 
76 at the end which is:

```
extern TwoWire Wire;
```

and it says

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   The type 'TwoWire' must implement the inherited pure virtual method 'Print::write'  Wire.h  /ArduinoCore/src    line 76 Code Analysis Problem

i give you the .cpp and header file they are the same as inside the arduino ide.
What can i do to fix this?

```
#ifndef TwoWire_h
#define TwoWire_h



#include <inttypes.h>
    #include "Stream.h"

    #define BUFFER_LENGTH 32

    class TwoWire : public Stream
    {
      private:
        static uint8_t rxBuffer[];
        static uint8_t rxBufferIndex;
        static uint8_t rxBufferLength;

        static uint8_t txAddress;
        static uint8_t txBuffer[];
        static uint8_t txBufferIndex;
        static uint8_t txBufferLength;

        static uint8_t transmitting;
        static void (*user_onRequest)(void);
        static void (*user_onReceive)(int);
        static void onRequestService(void);
        static void onReceiveService(uint8_t*, int);
      public:
        TwoWire();
        void begin();
        void begin(uint8_t);
        void begin(int);
        void beginTransmission(uint8_t);
        void beginTransmission(int);
        uint8_t endTransmission(void);
        uint8_t endTransmission(uint8_t);
        uint8_t requestFrom(uint8_t, uint8_t);
        uint8_t requestFrom(uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t);
        uint8_t requestFrom(int, int);
        uint8_t requestFrom(int, int, int);
        virtual size_t write(uint8_t);
        virtual size_t write(const uint8_t *, size_t);
        virtual int available(void);
        virtual int read(void);
        virtual int peek(void);
        virtual void flush(void);
        void onReceive( void (*)(int) );
        void onRequest( void (*)(void) );

        inline size_t write(unsigned long n) { return write((uint8_t)n); }
        inline size_t write(long n) { return write((uint8_t)n); }
        inline size_t write(unsigned int n) { return write((uint8_t)n); }
        inline size_t write(int n) { return write((uint8_t)n); }
        using Print::write;
    };

    extern TwoWire Wire;

    #endif
```

and the .cpp file:

```
extern "C" {
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <inttypes.h>
  #include "twi.h"
}

#include "Wire.h"

// Initialize Class Variables //////////////////////////////////////////////////

uint8_t TwoWire::rxBuffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
uint8_t TwoWire::rxBufferIndex = 0;
uint8_t TwoWire::rxBufferLength = 0;

uint8_t TwoWire::txAddress = 0;
uint8_t TwoWire::txBuffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
uint8_t TwoWire::txBufferIndex = 0;
uint8_t TwoWire::txBufferLength = 0;

uint8_t TwoWire::transmitting = 0;
void (*TwoWire::user_onRequest)(void);
void (*TwoWire::user_onReceive)(int);

// Constructors ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

TwoWire::TwoWire()
{
}

// Public Methods //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void TwoWire::begin(void)
{
  rxBufferIndex = 0;
  rxBufferLength = 0;

  txBufferIndex = 0;
  txBufferLength = 0;

  twi_init();
}

void TwoWire::begin(uint8_t address)
{
  twi_setAddress(address);
  twi_attachSlaveTxEvent(onRequestService);
  twi_attachSlaveRxEvent(onReceiveService);
  begin();
}

void TwoWire::begin(int address)
{
  begin((uint8_t)address);
}

uint8_t TwoWire::requestFrom(uint8_t address, uint8_t quantity, uint8_t sendStop)
{
  // clamp to buffer length
  if(quantity > BUFFER_LENGTH){
    quantity = BUFFER_LENGTH;
  }
  // perform blocking read into buffer
  uint8_t read = twi_readFrom(address, rxBuffer, quantity, sendStop);
  // set rx buffer iterator vars
  rxBufferIndex = 0;
  rxBufferLength = read;

  return read;
}

uint8_t TwoWire::requestFrom(uint8_t address, uint8_t quantity)
{
  return requestFrom((uint8_t)address, (uint8_t)quantity, (uint8_t)true);
}

uint8_t TwoWire::requestFrom(int address, int quantity)
{
  return requestFrom((uint8_t)address, (uint8_t)quantity, (uint8_t)true);
}

uint8_t TwoWire::requestFrom(int address, int quantity, int sendStop)
{
  return requestFrom((uint8_t)address, (uint8_t)quantity, (uint8_t)sendStop);
}

void TwoWire::beginTransmission(uint8_t address)
{
  // indicate that we are transmitting
  transmitting = 1;
  // set address of targeted slave
  txAddress = address;
  // reset tx buffer iterator vars
  txBufferIndex = 0;
  txBufferLength = 0;
}

void TwoWire::beginTransmission(int address)
{
  beginTransmission((uint8_t)address);
}

//
//  Originally, 'endTransmission' was an f(void) function.
//  It has been modified to take one parameter indicating
//  whether or not a STOP should be performed on the bus.
//  Calling endTransmission(false) allows a sketch to 
//  perform a repeated start. 
//
//  WARNING: Nothing in the library keeps track of whether
//  the bus tenure has been properly ended with a STOP. It
//  is very possible to leave the bus in a hung state if
//  no call to endTransmission(true) is made. Some I2C
//  devices will behave oddly if they do not see a STOP.
//
uint8_t TwoWire::endTransmission(uint8_t sendStop)
{
  // transmit buffer (blocking)
  int8_t ret = twi_writeTo(txAddress, txBuffer, txBufferLength, 1, sendStop);
  // reset tx buffer iterator vars
  txBufferIndex = 0;
  txBufferLength = 0;
  // indicate that we are done transmitting
  transmitting = 0;
  return ret;
}

//  This provides backwards compatibility with the original
//  definition, and expected behaviour, of endTransmission
//
uint8_t TwoWire::endTransmission(void)
{
  return endTransmission(true);
}

// must be called in:
// slave tx event callback
// or after beginTransmission(address)
size_t TwoWire::write(uint8_t data)
{
  if(transmitting){
  // in master transmitter mode
    // don't bother if buffer is full
    if(txBufferLength >= BUFFER_LENGTH){
      setWriteError();
      return 0;
    }
    // put byte in tx buffer
    txBuffer[txBufferIndex] = data;
    ++txBufferIndex;
    // update amount in buffer   
    txBufferLength = txBufferIndex;
  }else{
  // in slave send mode
    // reply to master
    twi_transmit(&data, 1);
  }
  return 1;
}

// must be called in:
// slave tx event callback
// or after beginTransmission(address)
size_t TwoWire::write(const uint8_t *data, size_t quantity)
{
  if(transmitting){
  // in master transmitter mode
    for(size_t i = 0; i < quantity; ++i){
      write(data[i]);
    }
  }else{
  // in slave send mode
    // reply to master
    twi_transmit(data, quantity);
  }
  return quantity;
}

// must be called in:
// slave rx event callback
// or after requestFrom(address, numBytes)
int TwoWire::available(void)
{
  return rxBufferLength - rxBufferIndex;
}

// must be called in:
// slave rx event callback
// or after requestFrom(address, numBytes)
int TwoWire::read(void)
{
  int value = -1;

  // get each successive byte on each call
  if(rxBufferIndex < rxBufferLength){
    value = rxBuffer[rxBufferIndex];
    ++rxBufferIndex;
  }

  return value;
}

// must be called in:
// slave rx event callback
// or after requestFrom(address, numBytes)
int TwoWire::peek(void)
{
  int value = -1;

  if(rxBufferIndex < rxBufferLength){
    value = rxBuffer[rxBufferIndex];
  }

  return value;
}

void TwoWire::flush(void)
{
  // XXX: to be implemented.
}

// behind the scenes function that is called when data is received
void TwoWire::onReceiveService(uint8_t* inBytes, int numBytes)
{
  // don't bother if user hasn't registered a callback
  if(!user_onReceive){
    return;
  }
  // don't bother if rx buffer is in use by a master requestFrom() op
  // i know this drops data, but it allows for slight stupidity
  // meaning, they may not have read all the master requestFrom() data yet
  if(rxBufferIndex < rxBufferLength){
    return;
  }
  // copy twi rx buffer into local read buffer
  // this enables new reads to happen in parallel
  for(uint8_t i = 0; i < numBytes; ++i){
    rxBuffer[i] = inBytes[i];    
  }
  // set rx iterator vars
  rxBufferIndex = 0;
  rxBufferLength = numBytes;
  // alert user program
  user_onReceive(numBytes);
}

// behind the scenes function that is called when data is requested
void TwoWire::onRequestService(void)
{
  // don't bother if user hasn't registered a callback
  if(!user_onRequest){
    return;
  }
  // reset tx buffer iterator vars
  // !!! this will kill any pending pre-master sendTo() activity
  txBufferIndex = 0;
  txBufferLength = 0;
  // alert user program
  user_onRequest();
}

// sets function called on slave write
void TwoWire::onReceive( void (*function)(int) )
{
  user_onReceive = function;
}

// sets function called on slave read
void TwoWire::onRequest( void (*function)(void) )
{
  user_onRequest = function;
}

// Preinstantiate Objects //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

TwoWire Wire = TwoWire();
```

Comment: The error message clearly says what you have to do, is your problem that you don't understand what it says? or that you don't know how to follow it?

Comment: i do not know how to follow it

Comment: Actually, the Arduino TwoWire code does implement the pure virtual Print::write() method, and the code actually compiles fine using the GNU toolchain. The problem is with Eclipse. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

this may be a bit late for you but... I also use Eclipse to do all my Arduino development, and I've seen this error. Its because Eclipse runs its own C++ code analysis tools against your  project code. (That is aside from the G++ toolchain.) The Eclipse ones sometimes have difficulty, or are over-zealous in spotting errors, even though the GNU Compiler compiles the code and generates your library jusst fine.

Look at the project Properties, C/C++ General section, and the Code Analysis tab. In the Syntax and Symantic list, the last check is called "Abstract Class cannot be Instantiated". Uncheck this, to disable the check. Then hit Apply.

Finally, right-click your project, and select "Run C/C++ Code Analysys" against it, which will clear the errors - no more red X.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM:** I had a similar problem, using the amazing Netbeans IDE, the compile error was:

```
C:\Arduino\libraries\Wire\Wire.h:76: error: **cannot declare variable 'Wire' to be of *abstract type* 'TwoWire'**
C:\Arduino\libraries\Wire\Wire.h:31: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'TwoWire':
c:/Arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Print.h:48: note:     virtual size_t Print::write(uint8_t)
```

Thanks to some guy here on StackOverFlow, I have understood that in case of missmatching between the virtual function prototype and the overridden version of that function in the derived class, the compiler complain.

**SOLUTION:** in Print.h, at line 48, I have deleted **= 0** from:

- `virtual size_t write(uint8_t) = 0;`
- `virtual size_t write(uint8_t);`

By the way, an advice, using Netbeans as IDE for developing software for Arduino make things a bit complicate for the setup... but than it gets easy to develop large and complicate software, thanks to Arduino and Netbeans!

http://leepike.wordpress.com/source-code/atomled-hs/makefile/

http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Netbeans